# morphism flat and relations

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, flatness

I want to know if the following result is true:

Let $I=<f_1,...,f_r>$ be an ideal of $K[x_1,x_2,...x_n,t_1,..,t_m]$. The morphism $\pi:V(I)\subset{K^{n+m}}\rightarrow{K^m}$, with $\pi(x,t)=t$, is flat (at t=0) iff every relation $g(x)=(g_1(x),...,g_r(x))$ between $f_1,...f_r$  $(\sum{g_i(x)f_i(x,0)=0})$ extends to a relation $g(x,t)$ between the $f_i(x,t)$.

Is this true? If not, what hypotheses are needed?

In any case, i want to read a proof!

Thanks in advance

Mike